# Grouping dates by dateadd and datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to group a bunch of dates by period, namely "month"

First I declare the table :

```
--inserts 36 dates every 10 days
create table sales (sales_date datetime, sales_amount decimal(12,2))
insert into sales (sales_date,sales_amount)
select '20140101',1000 union all
select '20140110',1000 union all
select '20140120',1000 union all
select '20140130',1000 union all
...
```

then I query entries grouped by period (of size = precision * months)

```
DECLARE @precision int = 1 --number of months

SELECT 
dateadd(month, (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) / @precision) * @precision, 0) as FromDate,
dateadd(month, @precision + (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) / @precision) * @precision, 0) as ToDate, 
count(*) as number
FROM sales
GROUP BY 
dateadd(month, (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) / @precision) * @precision, 0),
dateadd(month, @precision + (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) / @precision) * @precision, 0)
```

Results:

```
Test 1 : precision of 1 month
From : 01/01/2014, To : 01/02/2014, number : 4
From : 01/02/2014, To : 01/03/2014, number : 2
From : 01/03/2014, To : 01/04/2014, number : 3
From : 01/05/2014, To : 01/06/2014, number : 4
From : 01/06/2014, To : 01/07/2014, number : 3
From : 01/07/2014, To : 01/08/2014, number : 3
From : 01/08/2014, To : 01/09/2014, number : 3
From : 01/09/2014, To : 01/10/2014, number : 3
From : 01/10/2014, To : 01/11/2014, number : 3
From : 01/11/2014, To : 01/12/2014, number : 3
From : 01/12/2014, To : 01/01/2015, number : 2

Test 2 : precision of 2 months
From : 01/01/2014, To : 01/03/2014, number : 6
From : 01/03/2014, To : 01/05/2014, number : 6
From : 01/05/2014, To : 01/07/2014, number : 7
From : 01/07/2014, To : 01/09/2014, number : 6
From : 01/09/2014, To : 01/11/2014, number : 6
From : 01/11/2014, To : 01/01/2015, number : 5

Test 3 : precision of 3 months
From : 01/01/2014, To : 01/04/2014, number : 9
From : 01/04/2014, To : 01/07/2014, number : 10
From : 01/07/2014, To : 01/10/2014, number : 9
From : 01/10/2014, To : 01/01/2015, number : 8

Test 4 : precision of 4 months
From : 01/01/2014, To : 01/05/2014, number : 12
From : 01/05/2014, To : 01/09/2014, number : 13
From : 01/09/2014, To : 01/01/2015, number : 11
```

Everything works fine until Test 5 :

```
Test 5 : precision of 5 months
From : 01/10/2013, To : 01/03/2014, number : 6
From : 01/03/2014, To : 01/08/2014, number : 16
From : 01/08/2014, To : 01/01/2015, number : 14
```

The first line is annoying, I need it to start at 01/01/2014 like the previous precisions

Is there any way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the output that you're getting, i.e. I would expect to see `'FROM : '` to start of your select column list, but I don't, so that leads me to believe there's an intermediate step you're not showing us here, and that might be where your "translation" error is occurring.

Comment: `AND WHERE sales_date is not null`... that line doesn't need an `AND`

Comment: Results are just coming from my C# unit tests but sql server gives quite the same; Inserts and query compile anyway

Comment: Show your query results for test 5.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to divide by precision and again multiply by precision for the `FROM` column

here is what is happening

```
datediff(month, 0, sales_date)/5  -> 273.6   as it is integer division, it is converting to 273
```

further multiplying it by `273*5 = 1365` ( so 3 months are lost due to integer division)

so this one should work for you

```
DECLARE @precision int = 5 --number of months

SELECT 
dateadd(month, (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) ) , 0) as [From],
dateadd(month, @precision + (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) ) , 0) as [To], 
count(*) as number
FROM sales
GROUP BY 
dateadd(month, (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) ) , 0),
dateadd(month, @precision + (datediff(month, 0, sales_date) ), 0)
```

Comment: check this [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17674/38687) about the necessity of `/ @precision) * @precision`; without it, there is one period per month

Comment: @codablank1, then use precision as 5.0

Comment: @codablank1, also I still have precision in the second so u will get all points